# Is there way to retain session when curling into a url?

Tags: php, session, curl

Let's say I have a domain `foo.com` and it has a page called `foo.com/bar.php`

In one of the functions in the site, I try accessing `foo.com/bar.php` via cURL.

However, some stuff in `foo.com/bar.php` is dependent on the current session.

Hence, I want to retain the current session of the calling method into the cURL method.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You have to set options `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`/`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup some additional curl options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```

With above settings the cookies will be stored in cookie.txt :)